Has the Ministry of Education in Brazil ever published guidelines for career progression of federal university professors?
Act 12772 of 2012 determines some precepts for the promotion and career progression of university professors of federal universities.  Article 12 states that a performance evaluation will be observed for career progression.  Paragraph four says guidelines for the performance evaluation will be published by Ministry of Education.  Has such guidelines ever been published?

Art. 12. O desenvolvimento na Carreira de Magistério Superior ocorrerá mediante progressão funcional e promoção.
[...]
§ 2º A progressão na Carreira de Magistério Superior ocorrerá com base nos critérios gerais estabelecidos nesta Lei e observará, cumulativamente:
II - aprovação em avaliação de desempenho.
§ 4º As diretrizes gerais para o processo de avaliação de desempenho para fins de progressão e de promoção serão estabelecidas em ato do Ministério da Educação e do Ministério da Defesa, conforme a subordinação ou vinculação das respectivas IFE e deverão contemplar as atividades de ensino, pesquisa, extensão e gestão, cabendo aos conselhos competentes no âmbito de cada Instituição Federal de Ensino regulamentar os procedimentos do referido processo.


I could only find Portaria MEC 982/2013, which sets the guidelines just for Class E promotions.

Good finding anyhow.  Thank you so much.
